# awk: ^ backslash not last character on line

Tags: awk

Can anybody help in resolving this issue? Not sure wht it is giving problem.

```
ssh root@host1 "tail -f /data1/logs/logger.log | awk '{ if(\$0 ~ /^Mar|^Apr/) { printf(\"\\n%s\",\$0)  } if(\$0 \!~ /^Mar|^Apr/) { printf(\"%s\", \$0);} };' "
root@host1's password:
awk: { if($0 ~ /^Mar|^Apr/) { printf("\n%s",$0)  } if($0 \!~ /^Mar|^Apr/) { printf("%s", $0);} };
awk:                                                     ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Comment: Don't put a backslash there?  If you are grappling with Bash's Csh-style history expansion, try `set -H` to disable it.

Comment: @tripleee removing the backslash doesn't work - even with `set -H` I still get `bash: !~: event not found`. One solution is to use single quotes round the whole thing (as shown in my answer).

Comment: Sorry, I guess that should have been `set +H`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing over ssh, you can replicate the behaviour using `eval`. I made a test file (called `month`):

```
Mar line1
line2 line2
Apr line3
```

You have (at least) three options:

#### First option

Your two options are mutually exclusive, so you can sidestep the issue of escaping a `!` entirely by using two blocks with `next` in the first block:

```
eval "awk '/^Mar|^Apr/ { printf(\"\\n%s\",\$0); next } { printf(\"%s\", \$0) }' month"
```

If the condition is true, the first block is taken and `next` skips the rest. Note that I have removed the unnecessary `$0 ~` from the condition. The match is performed against the whole line by default.

#### Second option

You could actually just do this:

```
eval "awk '/^Mar|^Apr/ { \$0 = \"\\n\"\$0 } { printf(\"%s\", \$0) }' month"
```

1. If the line matches, precede it with a newline.
2. In all cases (no condition before the `{ }`), print the line.

#### Third option

If you wrap the overall command in single quotes, you don't need to do anything fancy with the `!`:

```
eval 'awk "{ if(/^Mar|^Apr/) { printf(\"\\n%s\",\$0) } if(!/^Mar|^Apr/) { printf(\"%s\", \$0)} }" month'
```

I recommend one of the other two solutions, I just thought that it would be worth showing that you *can* use `!` within the command if you need to.

Output for all three cases:

```
Mar line1line2 line2
Apr line3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up version of your `awk`

```
awk '/^Mar|^Apr/ {printf "\n%s",$0;next} {printf "%s",$0}'
```

This will test if `$0` (default, so need to add) is starting with `Mar` or `Apr`
If `yes` do `printf "\n%s",$0;next`. 
The `next` makes final code to be rune only if `$0` is not starting with `Mar` or `Apr`
Then run `printf "%s",$0`

Or just:

```
awk '/^Mar|^Apr/ {$0="\n"$0} {printf "%s",$0}'
```